I am about to buy a 2 to 4 Gb Dp + HDMI graphics card that works wiell with UBUNTU right out of the box. Would you please suggest one
An Amazon Choice MSI Gaming GeForce GT 1030 is 4 Gb graphics card has Linux issues.  I am about to buy a 2 to 4 Gb Dp + HDMI graphics card that works well with UBUNTU right out of the box.  Would you please suggest one.  (use;  video editing & driving two displays 15' away with 2 fiber-optic cables that the mobo can't both drive currently - no online games) {previous post advice seems dated and now incorrect about GeForce - technology has changed - for 2024 cards market}
NOTE: 73 yo on fixed income - spending wisely is important and the reason for the post.  Thank You for your time.

Hardware recommendations are generally considered to be off topic.

Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "Shopping or Hardware Recommendations" are off-topic on this more narrow focused Q&A support site.  Forums are better for these opinion geared questions (this is a Q&A site and not a forum)

Please ask here for hardware recommendations.
